# How do I resolve 'Location is required' in a JavaFX project

Tags: java, javafx

I have edited the FXML Document (View.fxml) in Scene Builder and tryed to call it in Application.start

View.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="174.0" layoutY="150.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Label layoutX="173.0" layoutY="103.0" text="CLick here" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader; 
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui/View.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have inserted a 'require javafx.fxml' in module-info.java and it shows a 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required' message on console.

The StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at javafx1/application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can you just post the full stacktrace? Your title references 'The type javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is not acessible' but then your question references 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required'.

Comment: Adding `requires javafx.fxml;` is the first step in solving the issue. The new error message indicates that the resource path is wrong though or that you haven't made the resources available via classpath.

Comment: I'm following a JavaFX tutorial and I've installed e(fx)clipse correctly. In the tutorial no one problem happened.

Comment: You've solved the "_The type javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is not accessible_" already by adding `requires javafx.fxml;`, thus that error is irrelevant to your question. I recommend you [edit] your question to better focus on your new problem of "_Location is required_". You mention following a tutorial where the tutorial works flawlessly. That means you must have done something different. When you [edit] your question please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and show us your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to delete module-info.java and add arguments
'''
--module-path  --add-modules 
'''

in my case, I had to set arguments

'''
--module-path C:\java-libs\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.controls
'''

to the JVM informing the library path and the modules needed to compile the code.

Comment: most probably not solving the real issue